# Bash - Adding titles into to a piped table command

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a simple script to output the content of the file students.txt as a basic table to the print file, which is then displayed.

```
#!/bin/bash

cat students.txt | column -t -s',' | sort -u -k3 > print.txt
cat print.txt
```

The output looks like as follows:

```
Consoling  ST  DWC  0900
Scribing   RA  DWC  1000
Gloater    AU  DWC  1100
Crimp      DI  DWC  1200
```

and so on. However I also want to be able to add headings for each column and have them align perfectly, as well as not being sorted. I have tried to use printf and echo but when piped into the command they do not display and I cannot align the columns correctly by printing the heading names outside of the pipe. The desired output I am looking for would look like this:

```
Family Name  Initials  Interviewer Initials  Interview Time
Consoling    ST        DWC                   0900
Scribing     RA        DWC                   1000
Gloater      AU        DWC                   1100
Crimp        DI        DWC                   1200
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a oneliner:

```
cat <(echo "Family Name,Initials,Interviewer Initials,Interview Time") <(sort -u -k3 -t ',' students.txt) | column -s ',' -t > print.txt
```

This makes use of [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution). The command inside `<()` is run and it's output appears as a filename. `cat` concatenates the two "files", that contain the outputs of `echo` (for the headers) and `sort` (to sort your `students.txt`).

- `sort` is run with option `-t ','` to specifiy "," as the delimiter.
- `column` is run with option `-s ','` to specify "," as the delimiter.

---

**EDIT** (thanks to @tripleee for pointing it out):

The oneliner can be modified, such that *Process Substitution* and `cat` isn't necessary:

```
{ echo "Family Name,Initials,Interviewer Initials,Interview Time"; sort -u -k3 -t ',' students.txt; } | column -s ',' -t > print.txt
```

`echo` and `sort` are grouped by `{}` and are executed in the current shell context. The redirection (pipe to `column`) is applied to the entire group. For reference: [Grouping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

Comment: The `cat` is pretty much useless.  Just run the `echo` and then the `sort`; they both print their results to standard output.

Comment: @tripleee I'm not 100% sure, if I got your suggestion right. To achieve, that both outputs of `echo` and `sort` will be treated as input for `column`, the two commands could be grouped, e.g.: `{ echo "$HEADER"; sort OPTIONS students.txt; } | column OPTIONS`. Correct?

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for pointing it out. I migrated your approach into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try a simple echo

```
cat students.txt | column -t -s',' | sort -u -k3 > print.txt
echo 'Family Name  Initials  Interviewer Initials  Interview Time' && cat print.txt
```

If you need them to be aligned based on your headings then you can use [column](https://linux.die.net/man/1/column)

```
column -t <<< "Family_Name  Initials  Interviewer_Initials  Interview_Time
Consoling  ST  DWC  0900
Scribing   RA  DWC  1000
Gloater    AU  DWC  1100
Crimp      DI  DWC  1200
"
Family_Name  Initials  Interviewer_Initials  Interview_Time
Consoling    ST        DWC                   0900
Scribing     RA        DWC                   1000
Gloater      AU        DWC                   1100
Crimp        DI        DWC                   1200
```

Note: spaces in column header is not allowed, else it would be treated as separate columns

Answer (score -1):

You put the header `Family Name, Initials, Interviewer Initials, Interview Time` before the contents of `students.txt` before sending it to the `column` comand, and I think that should do the trick.

Perhaps something like:

```
TEMP=$(mktemp)
TEMP2=$(mktemp)
cat students.txt | sort -u -k3 > $TEMP
echo Family Name, Initials, Interviewer Initials, Interview Time > $TEMP2
cat $TEMP >> $TEMP2
cat $TEMP2 | column -t -s',' > print.txt
rm -f $TEMP $TEMP2
cat print.txt
```

Comment: This kind of works, it inserts the heading into the table and adjusts the width of the columns correctly but, the issue is the headings are still half way down the table. More than likely due to sort.

Comment: Oh, yes, you are totally right. You need to do the sort before passing the data to `columns`. It should not be an issue in terms of the data produced. I'll fix it.

Comment: Thanks appreciate it :)

Comment: This should work. From what I understand sort understands both comma separated and space separated inputs. Otherwise I'm beat and you should probably do a larger bash script for it.

Comment: Just tried that, now the columns are right, i can see you done that using the append temp to temp2. However now it only displays the last line of the students.txt file in the table. I think this may be to do with sort again as in the source file each entry is separated by a comma.

Comment: Thanks I make some small edits and got it working. I had to compromise and make the echo include underlines for spaces. I added the column -t -s',' back to the cat students before sort, so it would be correctly sorted. Then I made the cat temp2 column just column -t