# Using awk for headings

Tags: bash, csv, awk

So I'm looking for some help with my headings for a text file.

A sample data file:

```
$ cat filename.txt
Consoling,ST,DWC,0900
Scribing,RA,DWC,1000
Gloater,AU,DWC,1100
Crimp,DI,DWC,1200
Moving,TI,DWC,1300
Handbook,EN,EBS,0900
Stifling,BA,EBS,1000
Unclothed,CR,EBS,1100
Until,IC,EBS,1200
```

This is the awk code that i have.

```
sort -t, -k3 -k4 filename.txt |
column -ts, |
awk ' { printf "%-8s %-2s %-3s %-3s\n" , "Family Name", "Initals", "Interviewer Initals", "Interview Time" }
{ printf "%-8s %-2s %-3s %3d\n", $1,$2,$3,$4 }
'
```

Which is outputting like this

```
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Consoling ST DWC 900
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Scribing RA DWC 1000
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Gloater  AU DWC 1100
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Crimp    DI DWC 1200
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Moving   TI DWC 1300
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Handbook EN EBS 900
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Stifling BA EBS 1000
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Unclothed CR EBS 1100
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time
Until    IC EBS 1200
```

But what i want it to look like is this.

```
Family Name Initals Interviewer Initals Interview Time

Consoling   ST      DWC                 0900
Scribing    RA      DWC                 1000
Gloater     AU      DWC                 1100
Crimp       DI      DWC                 1200
Moving      TI      DWC                 1300

Handbook    EN      EBS                 0900
Stifling    BA      EBS                 1000
Unclothed   CR      EBS                 1100
Until       IC      EBS                 1200
```

Does anyone know what i would have to change? Thanks

Comment: could you provide a snippet of your `filename.txt` file that matches with the current/desired results you've posted?

Comment: It's just unsorted CSV so it's like this `Moving,TI,DWC ,1300
Consoling,ST,DWC,0900
Unclothed,CR,EBS,1100`

Comment: This is very likely a duplicate of [Bash - Adding titles into to a piped table command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47329372/bash-adding-titles-into-to-a-piped-table-command/). The task required and the data provided are pretty much the same for both questions.

Comment: @C0DY:  a couple people with the same homework assignment? :-)

Answer (score 2):

To print the header once, place the header-specific printf command in a `BEGIN` block, eg:

```
awk '
BEGIN { printf ... header info... }
{ printf ... each data line ... }
'
```

And if you find yourself wanting to print something after processing the file, use an `END` block.

---

As for the rest of the output, I'm assuming you want to print a new line each time you see a new/different interviewer.

```
{ if ( last_interviewer != $3 ) { printf "\n" ; last_interviewr=$3 }
  printf ... each data line 
}
```

---

So, pulling it all together ...

The data file:

```
$ cat filename.txt
Consoling,ST,DWC,0900
Scribing,RA,DWC,1000
Gloater,AU,DWC,1100
Crimp,DI,DWC,1200
Moving,TI,DWC,1300
Handbook,EN,EBS,0900
Stifling,BA,EBS,1000
Unclothed,CR,EBS,1100
Until,IC,EBS,1200
```

And our `awk` solution:

```
$ sort -t, -k3 -k4 filename.txt |
column -ts, |
awk '
# print our header line once, before processing the actual data file:
BEGIN { printf "%-11s %-8s %-20s %-14s\n" , "Family Name", "Initials", "Interviewer Initials", "Interview Time" }

# now process our data file:
{ # if interviewer has changed, print an empty line and make note of our new last_interviewer:
  if ( last_interviewer != $3 ) 
     { printf "\n" ; last_interviewer=$3 }

  # print our current data line:
  printf "%-11s %-8s %-20s %04d\n", $1,$2,$3,$4
}'

Family Name Initials Interviewer Initials Interview Time

Consoling   ST       DWC                  0900
Scribing    RA       DWC                  1000
Gloater     AU       DWC                  1100
Crimp       DI       DWC                  1200
Moving      TI       DWC                  1300

Handbook    EN       EBS                  0900
Stifling    BA       EBS                  1000
Unclothed   CR       EBS                  1100
Until       IC       EBS                  1200
```

NOTE: Updated the a couple of the `printf` formats to address the wider headers and to left pad the 4th column with zero's.

Comment: **shrug**, wasn't paying much attention to the non-awk stuff ... just cut-n-pasted the OPs code but, yeah, now that you mention it ... could remove `column` and define `awk`'s FS=","; I'm guessing the OP was possibly looking at how to replace the commas and get fixed width columns prior to working on the `awk` code ... then forgot to (re)question the use of `column` ... ???